# Is there a way to instruct Eclipse to off-load memory when minimized?

Tags: eclipse, optimization, memory

i use eclipse with lot of plug-ins and will have more than one windows open at a time, and the memory usage is huge and my system hangs most of the time.

In FireFox we can set the flag config.trim_on_minimize=true and whenever FireFox is minimized the RAM Memory usage is reduced. (ie swapped), i am wondering is there any option in eclipse to do the same?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you work on Windows. It seems that the operating system (at least Windows XP) tend to swap java desktop application aggressively when they are minimized. Bringing back an application has some kind of 'sluggishness'.

To prevent this behaviour a 'fix' was implemented in Eclipse. You can read about it in [bug 85072](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=85072). I do not think you can change this.

One question: when your system starts hanging, all physical memory was gone and the entire system slows down or just Eclipse? In the latter case maybe the GC slows Eclipse so if you have free memory you may try to add more memory for Eclipse (increase -Xmx value in the eclipse.ini file).